# How do I preload my video in html and css code?

Tags: html, video

I need to preload my video, because there seems to be a 5-10 second delay from loading the tab to when the video loads. How do I specify in this code that the video need to be preloaded upon page load instead of tab load?

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3">
  <object id="flashObj" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,47,0">
  <param name="movie" value="http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?isVid=1&isUI=1" />
  <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" /><param name="flashVars" value="videoId=3286763175001&linkBaseURL=http%3A%2F%2Fmedianetwork.oracle.com%2Fvideo%2Fplayer%2F3286763175001&playerID=1787102915001&playerKey=AQ~~,AAAAAFcSbzI~,OkyYKKfkn3xPOduPEsqhjskdCvDxqymz&domain=embed&dynamicStreaming=true" />
  <param name="autoplay" value="true" />
  <param name="base" value="http://admin.brightcove.com" />
  <param name="seamlesstabbing" value="false" />
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
  <param name="swLiveConnect" value="true" />
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
  <embed src="http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?isVid=1&isUI=1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" flashVars="videoId=3286763175001&linkBaseURL=http%3A%2F%2Fmedianetwork.oracle.com%2Fvideo%2Fplayer%2F3286763175001&playerID=1787102915001&playerKey=AQ~~,AAAAAFcSbzI~,OkyYKKfkn3xPOduPEsqhjskdCvDxqymz&domain=embed&dynamicStreaming=true" base="http://admin.brightcove.com" name="flashObj" width="640" height="358" seamlesstabbing="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowFullScreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" swLiveConnect="true" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" style="width: 550px;"></embed>
```

There also seems to be a lot of parameters within this video, are the some that I can delete, i.e. nonessential parameters?

Comment: Quick question - you are using Brightcove's flash only embed - do you actually need this or could you use their Javascript embed? They suggest Flash only is for sites which will not permit Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a Brightcove player, using their Smart Player API is probably the easiest approach.

This includes events to tell you when the player has loaded and you can use this to then load the video immediately.

Take a look at the example at the link below, in particular the onTemplateReady call function which is called when the player is ready.

A simplified version of the callback function for your needs:

```
onTemplateReady = function (evt) {
      //Called when the video player is loaded and ready
      console.log("ready");
      modVP.loadVideoByID(videoID);  //modVP is the video player 'Module'
});
```

- http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/listening-events-using-smart-player-api